# Delphi: NetShareGetInfo and its path is empty

Tags: delphi, directory, share

I want to get the path of a share, and i do it this way:

```
Type
  TShareInfo2 = record
    shi2_netname: LPTSTR;
    shi2_type: DWORD;
    shi2_remark: LPTSTR;
    shi2_permissions: DWORD;
    shi2_max_uses: DWORD;
    shi2_current_uses: DWORD;
    shi2_path: LPTSTR;
    shi2_passwd: LPTSTR;
  End;

Function NetShareGetInfo(servername: LPWSTR; netname: LPWSTR; level: DWORD; bufptr: LPBYTE): DWORD; stdcall;

Var
  ShareInfo2: TShareInfo2;
  PChNetName, PChPath: array [0..255] of WideChar;
  ShareResult: Integer;
Begin
  With ShareInfo2 Do Begin
    shi2_netname := @PChNetName;
    shi2_type := 0;
    shi2_remark := nil;
    shi2_permissions := 0;
    shi2_max_uses := DWORD(-1);
    shi2_current_uses := 0;
    shi2_path := @PChPath;
    shi2_passwd := nil;
  End;
  ShareResult := NetShareGetInfo(Nil, PChar(FOld.sShareName), 2, @ShareInfo2);

  ShowMessage('Result='  + IntToStr(ShareResult)      +
              'PChPath=' + WideCharToString(PChPath)  );
End;
```

ShareResult is 0, but PChPath is empty.
The share exists of course.

What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are calling does not populate a record that you provide. It does not populate string buffers that you provide. Instead it allocates memory for the structure, and returns the address of that.

Your code should be:

```
Var
  ShareInfo2: ^TShareInfo2;
  ShareResult: Integer;
Begin
  ShareResult := NetShareGetInfo(Nil, PChar(FOld.sShareName), 2, @ShareInfo2);
  if Result = 0 then begin
    ShowMessage(WideCharToString(ShareInfo2.PChPath));
    NetApiBufferFree(ShareInfo2);
  end;
End;
```

There may be some mistakes here because I cannot see your declarations of `NetShareGetInfo`, `NetApiBufferFree` and `TShareInfo2`. But the essence of the problem is as I described.

Comment: My mistake was the missing ^

ShareInfo2: ^TShareInfo2;

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the answer, in effect